# Zariski topology on affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

As is defined in my textbook, the topology on an affine variety $X\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ is defined to be the subspace topology, i.e. open subset of $X$ are $X\backslash (X\cap Y)$ for some other affine variety $Y\subset \mathbb{A}^n$. But suppose we have an affine variety $Z=X\cup Y$ for affine varieties $X,Y$, $X=Z\backslash Y$ would become an open set according to the above definition. Shouldn't it be a closed set?

Comment: Actually, $X$ *contains* $Z \backslash Y$. It’s not equal unless $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint (and then $Z$ is disconnected and $X$ and $Y$ are open and closed).

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ and $Y$ don't intersect then $X$ and $Y$ are connected components of $X \cup Y$ (both open and closed). If they do intersect then $X \neq (X \cup Y) \setminus Y$.